# CSS Table Styling: Separate Borders and Borders for Row Groups

Tags: css, html-table

I've been struggling with styling this table. The header titles need to have separate underlines, and I need a separating line between the two groups of "Name" rows. (These will be different in the final render.)

This is what it looks like presently:
[image: Table not quite there]

This is what I'm looking for:
[image: Photoshopped. Kinda.]

I have a Codepen if you want to see it in action: [Table Styling Codepen](https://codepen.io/alfred3x/pen/GQrNLE)

I've been experimenting with border-collapse. I was able to get separate borders under some conditions, and the section separator under others. But there were always issues, such as no spacing between cells, so the styling looked very cramped.

Here's the HTML:

```
<table class="data-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th colSpan="2" class="title">Source</th>
        <th colSpan="2" class="title">Destination</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th colSpan="1" class="fieldname title">Field</th>
        <th colSpan="1" class="title">Value</th>
        <th colSpan="1" class="fieldname title">Field</th>
        <th colSpan="1" class="title">Value</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="bodySection">
    <tr>
        <td rowSpan="2" class="side-title">Name</td>
        <td class="fieldname src-data">Short Name</td>
        <td class="fieldvalue src-data"My Store/td>
        <td class="fieldname dest-data">Short Name</td>
        <td class="fieldvalue dest-data"><input type="text" value="My Store" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldname src-data">Long Name</td>
        <td class="fieldvalue src-data"My Store/td>
        <td class="fieldname dest-data">Long Name</td>
        <td class="fieldvalue dest-data"><input type="text" value="My Store" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="bodySection">
    <tr>
        <td rowSpan="2" class="side-title">Name</td>
        <td class="fieldname src-data">Short Name</td>
        <td class="fieldvalue src-data"My Store/td>
        <td class="fieldname dest-data">Short Name</td>
        <td class="fieldvalue dest-data"><input type="text" value="My Store" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldname src-data">Long Name</td>
        <td class="fieldvalue src-data"My Store/td>
        <td class="fieldname dest-data">Long Name</td>
        <td class="fieldvalue dest-data"><input type="text" value="My Store" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.data-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0 4px;
  border-collapse: separate;

  thead tr th {
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border-spacing: 0 5px;
  }
  .title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
    text-align: left;
    border-spacing: 0 5px;
  }

  .side-title {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    width: 25px;
  }
  .fieldname {
    width: 130px;
  }
  .fieldvalue.dest-data input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .bodySection {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #bbb;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  tr {
    // border-bottom: 10px solid #bbb;
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to get something like this?
  .bodySection tr:last-child td  {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .bodySection tr:first-child td  {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
Otherwise, can you post an image of what do you want to get?

Comment: @debe There you go. Added a shopped version of the table. (You wouldn't believe what I had to do to get that.)

Comment: Good. For the header, try this code (it doesn't work very well on IE11).

  .title {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, #bbb 0%, #bbb calc(100% - 5px), transparent calc(100% - 5px)) 0 99% / 100% 1px no-repeat;
    text-align: left;
  }

Comment: @debe It's scary that this works. Thanks buddy. Totally using this until something more "readable" comes along. I goosed the 5% to 10%. It's a little short on the far right value field, but I'm not going to quibble. Do you have something for separating the row groups?

Comment: I've added a better solution below (it works even with IE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your header with (I've added a div inside each th):

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
  <th colSpan="2" class="title"><div>Source</div></th>
        <th colSpan="2" class="title"><div>Destination</div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th colSpan="1" class="fieldname title"><div>Field</div></th>
        <th colSpan="1" class="title"><div>Value</div></th>
        <th colSpan="1" class="fieldname title"><div>Field</div></th>
        <th colSpan="1" class="title"><div>Value</div></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Than replace your .title with:

```
.title {
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
tr .title:last-child {
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.title div {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}
```

And your .bodySection with:

```
   .bodySection tr:last-child td { 
     border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb; 
     padding-bottom: 15px; 
  } 
  .bodySection tr:first-child td { 
    padding-top: 10px; 
  }
```

That's the snippet:

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.data-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0 4px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
  .title {
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
  tr .title:last-child {
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
  .title div {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
  }

  .side-title {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    width: 25px;
  }
  .fieldname {
    width: 130px;
  }
  .fieldvalue.dest-data {
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
  .fieldvalue.dest-data input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
  }
   .bodySection tr:last-child td { 
     border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb; 
     padding-bottom: 15px; 
  } 
  .bodySection tr:first-child td { 
    padding-top: 10px; 
  } 
  tr {
    // border-bottom: 10px solid #bbb;
  }
```

```html
<table class="data-table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
      <th colSpan="2" class="title"><div>Source</div></th>
   <th colSpan="2" class="title"><div>Destination</div></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th colSpan="1" class="fieldname title"><div>Field</div></th>
   <th colSpan="1" class="title"><div>Value</div></th>
   <th colSpan="1" class="fieldname title"><div>Field</div></th>
   <th colSpan="1" class="title"><div>Value</div></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody class="bodySection">
  <tr>
   <td rowSpan="2" class="side-title">Name</td>
   <td class="fieldname src-data">Short Name</td>
   <td class="fieldvalue src-data"My Store/td>
   <td class="fieldname dest-data">Short Name</td>
   <td class="fieldvalue dest-data"><input type="text" value="My Store" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="fieldname src-data">Long Name</td>
   <td class="fieldvalue src-data"My Store/td>
   <td class="fieldname dest-data">Long Name</td>
   <td class="fieldvalue dest-data"><input type="text" value="My Store" /></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody class="bodySection">
  <tr>
   <td rowSpan="2" class="side-title">Name</td>
   <td class="fieldname src-data">Short Name</td>
   <td class="fieldvalue src-data"My Store/td>
   <td class="fieldname dest-data">Short Name</td>
   <td class="fieldvalue dest-data"><input type="text" value="My Store" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="fieldname src-data">Long Name</td>
   <td class="fieldvalue src-data"My Store/td>
   <td class="fieldname dest-data">Long Name</td>
   <td class="fieldvalue dest-data"><input type="text" value="My Store" /></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you rock! Thx. I'll have more table styling questions coming up. I did use that `div` within `td` thing to rotate "Name" title on the left. I should have thought to use it for borders too.